# Calculation of $f(\frac{3}{5})$, given that $f:D(0, 2)\to\,\mathbb{C}$ is analytic so that $f(\frac{2}{n})=\frac{1}{n+1}, n = 2, 3,...$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following exercise:

Let $f:D(0, 2)\to\,\mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function so that $f(\frac{2}{n})=\frac{1}{n+1}, n = 2, 3,...$ Calculate $f(\frac{3}{5})$.

And this is my approach. I replaced $\frac{2}{n}$ with $m$. So the expression above transforms to $f(m)=\frac{m}{m+2}$. If I consider $f(z)=\frac{z}{z+2}$, this function is analytic in the domain and satisfies the condition above. So if I use this function, I calculate $f(\frac{3}{5})=\frac{3}{13}$. My question is, why would this $f$ be the only one that satisfies those criteria, so that I can use it to calculate $f(\frac{3}{5})$?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you heard of the [identity theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have already done most of the hard work. Consider $g : D(0, 2) \to \Bbb C$ defined as $$g(z) = \frac{z}{z + 2}.$$
Then, $f$ and $g$ agree on the subset $$S := \left\{\frac{2}{2}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{2}{4}, \ldots\right\} \subset D(0, 2) =: \Omega.$$
Note that $S$ has a limit point in $\Omega$, namely $0$.

By the [Identity Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem), it follows that $f = g$ on $\Omega$ and you are done.